# Toshiba T110 brightness control "FN" doesn't work (Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 32 bit)

Tags: brightness, backlight

I recently installed Ubuntu 12.04 32 bit in my Toshiba T110 laptop, and the brightness control doesn't work.

I have tried gedit `/etc/default/grub`, and have modified the "quite splash" to many suggestion that i have come across, like:

`"quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` 
and `"quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux"` 
and `"quiet splash acpi_osi=Linux acpi_backlight=vendor"`

but nothing seems to work, I mean i can see the brightness indicator moving but the brightness is set to highest all the time, Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got this to work running the following:

first I updated the kernel with the line
`sudo apt-get install linux-image-generic-lts-quantal`

then I updated the x stack with the line 
 `sudo apt-get install xserver-xorg-lts-quantal`

after that I ran `sudo gedit /etc/default/grub` I modified where it says `"quite splash"` to `"quiet splash acpi_backlight=vendor"` saved it.

updated grub using `sudo update-grub` , rebooted the system and now the "FN" works like magic

Answer (score 0):

you can try below command

```
xrandr --output LVDS1 --brightness 0.89
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer David, I ran the line and here what I've got:  `xrandr --output LVDS --brightness 0.89
warning: output LVDS not found; ignoring
xrandr: Need crtc to set gamma on. `

Comment: ```xrandr``` first , and chose your device id(may be VGA***)

Comment: I realy appreciate your help David, any suggustions

Comment: replace LVDS to **LVDS1** is ok